# ef core. Add unique value in row during insert

Tags: .net, triggers, entity-framework-core

I have no idea how to to that in ef, mayby using sql procedure is best option.
Suppuse I have table

| ID | Type | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |

On each insert I want to calculate "Counter" column by 'Type' occurence. So if I insert Type=1 third time, then Counter should have 3. I use EF code-first. I was thinking about insert with subquery on Counter, but EF does not support it (RAW insert is not a option). I can of course calculate in code and insert, but there is a chance, that during one operation, another would calculate the same value. For know I use trigger after insert, where I count Type occurence, also I added unique constraint on (TYPE,Counter). Is there another better soulution? For clearance, I need this for document version by its type.

I expect Counter will be unique. Is counting in trigger is good idea? For clearance, I need this for document version by its type.

Comment: What happens to your data in case of update/delete?

Comment: The trigger looks acceptable to me. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#update-timestamp)

Comment: Column with Type is readonly. I will not delete any row.